# How to get high and low for a specific time period

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to write a strategy in Pinescript for trading view and I have to get the high and low values during a certain time period. Like 10:00 to 10:30 AM. In the documentation I can see the time range but not sure how to get high and low for that particular time period.

Comment: Hey and welcome. Can you share some code, what have you tried. Even a lik to the documentaion which you have used, helps all other to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

This code is modified from [this PineCoders FAQ entry](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-track-highslows-for-a-specific-period-of-time). Note that the hi/lo develops as the monitored period of time elapses:

```
//@version=4
study("Session hi/lo", "", true)
noPlotOutside = input(true, "Don't plot outside of hours")
showHi = input(true, "Show highs")
showLo = input(true, "Show lows")
srcHi = input(high, "Source for Highs")
srcLo = input(low, "Source for Lows")
timeAllowed = input("1000-1030", "Allowed hours", input.session)

// Check to see if we are in allowed hours using session info on all 7 days of the week.
timeIsAllowed = time(timeframe.period, timeAllowed + ":1234567")
var hi = 10e-10
var lo = 10e10
if timeIsAllowed
    // We are entering allowed hours; reset hi/lo.
    if not timeIsAllowed[1]
        hi := srcHi
        lo := srcLo
    else
        // We are in allowed hours; track hi/lo.
        hi := max(srcHi, hi)
        lo := min(srcLo, lo)

plot(showHi and not(noPlotOutside and not timeIsAllowed)? hi : na, "Highs", color.blue, 3, plot.style_circles)
plot(showLo and not(noPlotOutside and not timeIsAllowed)? lo : na, "Lows", color.fuchsia, 3, plot.style_circles)
```

[image]

*Disclosure: the link in this answer points to a PineCoders FAQ entry. I am a member of the PineCoders community and I most probably wrote that FAQ entry. PineCoders is a TradingView-supported group of volunteer Pine coders and PineCoders' website is strictly educational. Neither TradingView nor PineCoders benefits financially from sending traffic to pinecoders.com, and the site contains no affiliate/referral links.*

Comment: Thanks a lot @PineCoders-LucF, the above mentioned code works to get the highs and lows within the time frame. I am wondering if I can get the max of highest values in the time period. I tried the code with below modifications but it didnt help. I tried adding the code snippet in the comments but it is too long to post so basically I tried to create an array and added the 'hi' value in the else part to it and tried to get average of the array by using array.max(maxHigh). But this is plotting one value across the chart.

Comment: Can you further explain what you mean by "get the max of highest values in the time period"? That's what the posted code does, imo, so I don't think I understand your requirement correctly.

Comment: Hi @PineCoders-LucF I am meaning to say I want to collect all the high values shown during that particular time frame and get the highest value among those. Like if I have the chart to 5 mins, I will be getting 6 high values from 1000 to 1030 . I would like to get the highest value among these 6.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon Vignesh,

I am interested in your question and if you get an answer I would be grateful if you could share.

I am not sure if the below might assist you. It captures the high and low of the first 60 mins after UTC 00:00.

```
    //Session Rules
    bartimeSess = time('D')
    newbarSess = bartimeSess != bartimeSess[1]


    high_range = valuewhen(newbarSess,high,0)
    low_range = valuewhen(newbarSess,low,0)

//Calcul For Opening Range
locHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", high_range)
locLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, "60", low_range)
range = locHigh - locLow

//Plot Statements For Initial Balance
plot(time(timeframe.period) > 0 ? locHigh : na,title="IB High", color=color.blue, transp=20, linewidth=2)
plot(time(timeframe.period) > 0 ? locLow : na,title="IB Low", color=color.blue, transp=20, linewidth=2)


//Plot Statements For Medium of IB range
plot(locLow + range/2,title="IB Medium", color=color.green, transp=20, linewidth=2)
```