# I want to add a plus sign to my chart, How can I do that?

Tags: pine-script, indicator

In Pine Script, I want to write a code that first, detects low price of the look back period 200 candles, then adds a plus sign like the following picture.
Thank you
[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xo58.png)

Comment: I want to write an indicator to signal short position. I want it to look back for 200 candles and detect the lowest price and adds a plus sign. once the price hits the plus sign opens a short position but for now I only want to add a plus sign like the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Armin,

Have a look at this post it might help or get you started with experimenting.

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65590923/how-to-get-high-and-low-for-a-specific-time-period/65598255#65598255)

If you were to change circle to cross and only show the low and change the time period.

As you mention above 200 candle look back and the image you provided was 5 min TF so about 16ish hours data.

Daniel